# Removing Global Filter in Entity Framework Core 3.1.8

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

- Does anybody know how to remove a **global filter** on run time?
- I have a multi-tenant application that includes a global filter as tenant id.
- I want to have a super-tenant that does not have this filter therefore when I detected a super tenant I want to remove this filter from the configuration of entities.
  -There is an IgnoreQueryFilters but it is only useful locally.

Global Filter Reference Microsoft
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters

```
public class MerchantConfiguration : TenantEntityConfiguration<Merchant>
{
    public MerchantConfiguration(ITenantContext context) : base(context) { }

    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Merchant> builder)
    {
        base.Configure(builder);

        builder.ToTable($"AppMerchants");
        builder.HasKey(e => new { e.MerchantId, e.TenantId });

        builder.Property(e => e.PostalCode).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(e => e.IndustryCode).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(e => e.State).HasMaxLength(3);
        
        builder.HasOne(e => e.MerchantCategory).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.MerchantCategoryCode).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        builder.HasOne(e => e.Industry).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.IndustryCode).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
       
        builder.HasIndex(e => e.LocationId);
        builder.HasIndex(e => e.PostalCode);
        builder.HasIndex(e => e.City);
        builder.HasIndex(e => e.Name);
    }
}
```

- 

```
    public class TenantEntityConfiguration<TEntity> : AuditableEntityConfiguration<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class, ITenantEntity
{
    protected readonly ITenantContext context;

    public TenantEntityConfiguration(ITenantContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
    {
        base.Configure(builder);
        
        builder.Property(e => e.TenantId).HasMaxLength(64);
        builder.HasIndex(e => e.TenantId);
         builder.HasQueryFilter(e => e.TenantId == context.TenantId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just show how you define global query filter and i’ll give you solution.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters I defıne global query as explained in the documentation

Comment: I know how to define global query filters. I'm interesting how you define them in your application.

Comment: I updated the question with code now, thank you for your effort.

Comment: Well I have added preliminary sample. but in your case it will not work. Do you have `MyDbContext` which implements `ITenantContext`? Problem that we have to know type of this context in `TenantEntityConfiguration `

Comment: In my case, I want to apply filters only when a user is not a super tenant. After build isSuperTenant is false but after a super tenant login, it became true. I need to remove HasQueryFilter dynamically on run time globally. It must be applied at least once and must be removed after super tenant login.         
if(!context.isSuperTenant){
  builder.HasQueryFilter(e => e.TenantId == context.TenantId);
}

Comment: So, my answer contains solution. Set `context.TenantId = null`.

Comment: It is not a solution for my case, I need to disable the query filter with a condition by respecting current tenant.

Comment: Give me a sample of the condition.

Comment: I already give it in above which is 
if(!context.isSuperTenant){ builder.HasQueryFilter(e => e.TenantId == context.TenantId); } 
if(context.isSuperTenant) { //  I need to remove query filter here}

Comment: Updated answer. What I have to say, you cannot disable defining query filter - you have to define always. Otherwise you need another entity configuration.

Comment: I have tried to disable cache and apply another entity configuration. It does not apply the new configuration after applying first one.

Comment: So, do right now via flags in query filter. I have reviewed EF code, it is almost one way to do that.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: I am not vandalizing it. The documentation link that I share has a better example about the problem the code was unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Well, will try to show simplest sample, when defining filters in context's `OnModelCreating` method

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
   .HasQueryFilter(b => this.CurrentTenantId == null 
      || this.IsSuperTenant
      || b.TenentId == this.CurrentTenantId.Value);
```

It expects that you DbCcontext has this property:

```cs
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
   public int? CurrentTenantId { get; set; }
   ...
}
```